# React SSR : How can my component get the URL search URL parameters in its render method

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

I am unclear how to get the request's search parameters to be available in a component when reading React apps on the server.

**Client Side Rendering**

In a Client side rendered React application I know how to get the request's search parameters passed onto the component used for that route.

The code below is in my CSR app. See the 2nd route, I am getting the value of the search param "b" and passing it onto my component as the "name" property.

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />

    <Route
      exact
      path="/a/:id"
      render={(props) => {
        const params = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search);
        const b = params.get('b');
        return ( <MyComp id={props.match.params.id} name={b} /> );
      }}
    />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Therefore if my URL was

```
http://host:port/a/b=George
```

MyComp's

```
this.props.b
```

will return "George". The component can get this value in its "render" method

```
render(){
    const { name } = this.props;
}
```

**Server Side Rendering**

In my SSR app the routes are defined using a route config

```
export default [
  {
    ...Home,
    path: '/',
    exact: true,
    title: 'Home Screen',
  },
  {
    ...MyComp,
    path: '/a/:id',
    exact: true,
    title: 'My Component'
  },
];
```

There is no props available here, so unlike the CSR application I can not get the "props.location.search"   and send to the component.

This Routes object is used in my server and client renderers:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <StaticRouter .... }>
    <div>{renderRoutes(Routes)}</div>
  </StaticRouter>
</Provider>


<Provider store={store}>
  <BrowserRouter ....>
    <div>{renderRoutes(Routes)}</div>
  </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>,
```

In my component "render" method, I have no way to get the value of the "b" parameter. "this.props.location" does not have any value in its "search" property.

How to do make the search url parameters available to my components render method in a React SSR app.

I did wonder if could do something like the following, but obviously "props" is not known in this context

```
{
    ...MyComp,
    path: '/a/:id',
    exact: true,
    title: 'My Component',
    name: new URLSearchParams(props.location.search).get('b')
  },
```

I know i can get the information in my Express Server code from the "req.query".  But all i can do with that value is pass it to my components "loadData" method, but this does not make it available in my render method.

```
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const store = createStore();
    
  console.log(req.query) // this gives me the value of "b"

  // I could pass req.query to the component's loadData but that does not gain me anything
  const promises = matchRoutes(Routes, req.path)
    .map(({ route, match }) => (
        route.loadData ? route.loadData(store, match, req.query) : null)
      );
```

Any ideas how to make the search URL parameters available to my route component's render method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution to this issue. I am not sure its the best solution but it appears to work in both server and client side rendering.

**Server Side**

On the server side, in the Express Server file, add the "req.query" to each Route in the Routes object just before its used in MatchRoutes

```
import Routes from '../pages/Routes';
...

server.get('*', (req, res) => {

    Routes.forEach((r)=>{
      r.queryParams = req.query;
    });

    const promises = matchRoutes(Routes, req.path)

    ....
```

This makes the "queryParams" available in the component when rendering server side, so the value of "b" query param can be obtained

```
render() { 
    const { route } = this.props;    
    const { queryParams } = route;
    
    const name = queryParams.b;
    ....
```

**Client Side**

The client side Routes will not have the "queryParams" populated, but "this.props.location.search" has the values so we can get the value from there.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { location } = this.props;
    const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    const name = params.get('b');
    this.setState({ name });
```

**Rendering the name**

In the component's render method you have to check if its being rendered client side or server side and use the relevant data.

```
render() {  
    // server side rendering values
    const { route } = this.props;    
    const { queryParams } = route;
    // client side rendering values
    const { name } = this.state;

    let title = name; // will be undefined in SSR
    if (queryParams){
      // SSR set the name
      title = queryParams.b;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for the server side part is to add the req.query to the context object which contains all the data created when calling the matched route's components method.

```
const context = { data, requestQueryParams: req.query };
```

This context object is then included on the server side router

```
<StaticRouter context={context} ...>
```

Components can then get any data from this context object when on the server side

```
  const { staticContext } = this.props;
  data = staticContext.data;
  const myQueryParamValue = staticContext.requestQueryParams.myQueryParamName;
```